# Substitute in only field 3

Tags: awk

What's wrong with my syntax here?

```
awk -F '|' 'sub/\s*\w*/,"Visit our website!","$3"' merchant_report
```

it's suppose to turn

```
|bob|jones| blagblag| texas
|tom|markus| | alabama
```

into

```
|bob|jones|Visit our website!| texas
|tom|markus| | alabama
```

Comment: 1) Not all awks will support \s and \w. 2) sub() is a function not the "s" command from sed. 3) You probably want to put the commands in the action part of the awk body, not the contition (aka pattern) part. See the awk manual for now, http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html, and buy the matching book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1):

this line may do what you want:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" 'NR==1{$4="Visit our website!"}1' file
```

in your awk codes:

- you have had `FS` to separate the fields, you don't need the `sub` func., just set `$3` directly.
- even if with `sub( )` function, your syntax is not correct. you can get detail info by `man gawk`
- it is actually not `$3`, it is `$4`. because your line starting with `|`
- if you want to just change the first line, you should add `NR==1` otherwise awk will do the change on all lines

example with the code:

```
kent$  cat file
    |bob|jones| blagblag| texas
    |tom|markus| | alabama

kent$  awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" 'NR==1{$4="Visit our website!"}1' file
    |bob|jones|Visit our website!| texas
    |tom|markus| | alabama
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` you would just assign the field the new value for the given line. If you are more comfortable with the substitution approach try `sed`:

```
sed '1s/|[^|]*/|Visit our website!/3' file
|bob|jones|Visit our website!| texas
|tom|markus| | alabama
```